# Page not found (404) in Django Output

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

`Urls.py:`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="blogHome"),
    path("blogpost/<int:id>/", views.blogpost, name="blogHome")
]
```

`Views.py:`

```
django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Blogpost

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html')

def blogpost(request, id):
    post.Blogpost.objects.filter(post_id = id)[0]
    print(post)
    return render(request, 'blog/blogpost.html')
```

`Models.py:`

```
from django.db import models

class Blogpost(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    head0 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    chead0 = models.CharField(max_length=10000, default="")
    head1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    chead1 = models.CharField(max_length=10000, default="")
    head2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
    chead2 = models.CharField(max_length=10000, default="")
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/images', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Error**

[image: Error Image which i see in output]

**Error in cmd**

Not Found: /blog/blogpost

[21/Jun/2022 12:29:33] "GET /blog/blogpost HTTP/1.1" 404 2678

Comment: You haven't defined a path for `/blog/blogpost`.

Comment: url patterns should have unique names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current error means Django doesn't find anything with the route `blog/blogpost`, it is because you have also defined an `id` to be pass in route, so kindly try `http....blog/blogpost/1/` any `id` you can give.

Also, `id` is generally used to get a single object, and you are doing filtering on it. I think you should use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) if you want to retrieve single object.

As [@lvanStarostin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5921826/ivan-starostin) stated in the above comment that URL patterns should also have unique names. You should change one of the names.

> `Note:` Models are classes of python so they must be written in **PascalCase**, so you may change your model name to `BlogPost` from <s>`Blogpost`</s>.